# How to compare time between night time to morning time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to compare a time between a several time range. And one of the range is from night time to morning time for example 2200-0459. How to do this in Java Script? Currently I just manage to compare from morning to evening or evening to night time e.g. 0500-0759.

Here is the code:

```
function setRowBGColor()
    {
        var time = $("#DrugTime option:selected").text().replace(':', '');
        $("#TimeSlot").find('tr').each(function (i) {
            var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
                timeslot = $tds.eq(0).text(),
                timerange = $tds.eq(1).text().split('-'); 
            if(time >= timerange[0] && time <= timerange[1])
            {
                alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nTime Slot: ' + timeslot + '\Time Range: ' + timerange[0] + '-' + timerange[1]);
            }
        });
    }
```

And here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5qGfx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a typo for range 6. I assume it should have been 1500-1859.

```
function setRowBGColor() {
    var time = parseInt($("#DrugTime option:selected").text().replace(':', ''));
    $("#TimeSlot").find('tr').each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            timeslot = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            timerange = $tds.eq(1).text().split('-'),
            lowerBound = parseInt(timerange[0]),
            upperBound = parseInt(timerange[1]);

        // Fix time for compare.
        if (upperBound < lowerBound) {
            upperBound += 2400;

            if (!((time >= lowerBound) && (time <= upperBound)))
                time += 2400;
        }

        if (time >= lowerBound && time <= upperBound) {
            alert('Row ' + (i + 1) + ':\nTime Slot: ' + timeslot + '\nTime Range: ' + timerange[0] + '-' + timerange[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Q4dz5/2/

Comment: You are correct there's a typo over there and I didn't see it. Thank you for pointing that out and thank you for your solution. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: If the end time of the range is lower than the start time (that is that case if the interval is spanning around midnight) – then it is enough, if the time is either greater than (equal to) the start time, **or** lesser than (equal to) the end time:

```
if (
  time >= timerange[0] && time <= timerange[1]
  ||
  timerange[1] < timerange[0] && (time >= timerange[0] || time <= timerange[1])
)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5qGfx/2/

Comment: Thank you. Your solution works after I edited the typo error in Time Slot number 6. Here is the update from your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5qGfx/25/

Answer (score 1):

Added a few twists to the one by @Johan

1. Checking for numbers is better than checking with strings.
2. Keeping the if check simple than putting in all the logic inside that check

http://jsfiddle.net/aravindbaskaran/VWXrD/

```
function setRowBGColor() {
    var rows = $("#TimeSlot").find('tr');
    var lowestBound = parseInt($(rows[1]).find("td").eq(1).text().split('-')[0]);
    var time = $("#DrugTime option:selected").text().replace(':', '');
    time = parseInt(time, 10);
    if(time < lowestBound){
        time += 2400;
    }
    rows.each(function (i) {
        var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
            timeslot = $tds.eq(0).text(),
            timerange = $tds.eq(1).text().split('-');
        timerange[0] = parseInt(timerange[0],10);
        timerange[1] = parseInt(timerange[1],10);
        if(timerange[1] < timerange[0]){
            timerange[1] += 2400;
        }
        if (!isNaN(timerange[0])&& time >= timerange[0] && time <= timerange[1]) {
            alert('Row ' + (i - 1) + ':\nTime Slot: ' + timeslot + '\nTime Range: ' + timerange[0] + '-' + timerange[1]);
        }
    });
}
```

UPDATE : Improved if checks

Comment: I can't use if statement as the time ranges are from database and will change regularly. Second, your fiddle is not working as it should. If I select 02:00 for example, the system should only display time range 2200-0459.

Comment: I think it is because for 02:00 there are two ranges - 2200-0459 and 1500-0659. Can you tell me which "if" statement you are referring to?

Comment: Apologize for my mistake. It's a typo error. Your solution works after fixing it. The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VWXrD/4/

Comment: No problem. The above snippet should performs a little better than the current accepted answer, since it avoids an extra check inside the loop, i.e. lesser operations in the loop, faster the loop

Comment: Yes you are correct. It is just that I can't hardcode like this 'if(time<500)' as the time range comes from database and it might be different between facility/client.

Comment: Exactly, now I understood that from your first comment. Now it is calculating based on if the selected time is lower than the lowestBound. Updated the fiddle too, try it and let me know if thats correct.

Comment: And there is this possibility - If there are overlapping bounds like so in the future -> 2200-0459, 1500-0659, etc. the other snippet will keep adding 2400 for every found result, thereby selecting only one time slot. Not sure if this applies to you, but just a possiblity